# npm install error - invalid package.json

Tags: json, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, npm

I'm using [this](http://www.xorcode.com/2013/08/22/getting-started-with-node-js-using-oauth2-in-mean/) tutorial to understand implementing oauth2 in Node.js.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "coffee -w server.coffee"
  },  
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.3.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "coffee-script": "latest",
    "passport-http": "latest",
    "passport-http-bearer": "latest",
    "passport-oauth2-client-password": "latest",
    "oauth2orize": "latest",
    "debug" "~0.7.2"
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected string
npm ERR! File: /Users/jashua/Desktop/auth/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/jashua/Desktop/auth
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! file /Users/jashua/Desktop/auth/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/Desktop/auth/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my package.json?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error means exactly what it states, the JSON in your `package.json` is not valid and can't be parsed properly. Change `"debug" "~0.7.2"` to `"debug": "~0.7.2"`.

Comment: Also if you install your dependencies with `--save` npm flag you wont have to edit `package.json` manually

Comment: Similar problem here. In my case I was missing a comma at the end of a dependency: "requirejs": "\*", (<-- was missing) "karma-requirejs" : "\*"

Comment: in my case nothing is wrong, i checked jsonlint.com. What could be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue caused by changes that I had made to my `package.json` file. I just reverted to my backup version of the `package.json` file. I attached that below if anyone else needs one:

```
{"name": "OpenShift-Sample-App",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "OpenShift Sample Application",
 "keywords": [
   "OpenShift",
   "Node.js",
   "application",
   "openshift"
 ],
 "author": {
   "name": "OpenShift",
   "email": "ramr@example.org",
   "url": "http://www.openshift.com/"
 },
 "homepage": "http://www.openshift.com/",
 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "https://github.com/openshift/origin-server"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": ">= 0.6.0",
   "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "express": "~3.4.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {},
 "bundleDependencies": [],
 "private": true,
 "main": "server.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm cache verify`

Fixes it on Windows 10, run it with an Administrator command prompt Window.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this page due to the same npm error, but a different cause. After viewing the log files, I realized that npm did not like my comment on the top line of the file.

```
// package.json
{ ...
}
```

After removing all comments, npm ran through everything beautifully. My comment was not necessary, so I'm fine as it is. But if you require comments within your xml, see [How do I add comments to package.json for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221579/how-do-i-add-comments-to-package-json-for-npm-install?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might have some weird unicode chars in your `package.json`. For example you might have `\u00A0` (unicode non-breaking space) instead of a space somewhere. It looks the same in editor, so beware.

(I just had such problem after copying a small piece of config from a blog.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to fix package.json related issue.

npm cache clean

Comment: Please elaborate on what this does to fix the OP's issue and supply a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

My project was in D:\wwwroot\Projetos 2017\Android\PluginTest\PluginTest\plugins\cordova-plugin-iservice

The problem is space between Projetos(here)2017

I removed space to:
D:\wwwroot\Projetos2017\Android\PluginTest\PluginTest\plugins\cordova-plugin-iservice

and Work fine

Comment: What does this have to do with the question