# How can you preserve comments in a package.json file after running yarn add

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am using npm and yarn to manage dependencies for a project. As suggested in this question: [How do I add comments to package.json for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221579/how-do-i-add-comments-to-package-json-for-npm-install) I'm using the following format to be able to include comments in the pacakge.json. Here's a sample:

```
"scripts": {
  "////":"LIVE BROWSER RELOAD",
  "serve:patternlab": "BUILD_TO='patternlab' browser-sync start --config browsersync.config.js",
  "serve:site": "browser-sync start --config browsersync.config.js",

  "////":"LINTING COMMANDS",
  "lint:js": "eslint $npm_package_config_src_js --ignore-pattern **/vendor/**/*.js || true",
  "lint:css": "sass-lint $npm_package_config_src_css**/*.scss -v -q || true",
  "lint": "npm-run-all -p lint:js lint:css",
}
```

This format makes it easy to see what each set of scripts is doing. However, whenever I run `yarn add` to add a new package, it strips out all the comments except the last one (which gets moved to the top of the `scripts` object), and strips out the line breaks. Is there anything I can do to avoid this happening?

Comment: I have found a way to preserve the comments: add a unique identifier to each one, e.g. `"////a": "LIVE BROWSER RELOAD",` and `////b": "LINTING COMMANDS`. However, the whitespace still gets removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was the closest I was able to get in to what I wanted to achieve. The following is preserved after running `yarn add` and adds some separation to each set of scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "//LIVE BROWSER RELOAD": "--------------------------------------------------------------------------",
    "serve:patternlab": "BUILD_TO='patternlab' browser-sync start --config browsersync.config.js",
    "serve:site": "browser-sync start --config browsersync.config.js"
    ,
    "//LINTING COMMANDS": "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------",
    "lint:js": "eslint $npm_package_config_src_js --ignore-pattern **/vendor/**/*.js || true",
    "lint:css": "sass-lint $npm_package_config_src_css/**/*.scss -v -q || true",
    "lint": "npm-run-all -p lint:js lint:css"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to support `JSON` comments:

1. Use `JSON5`.
2. Specify the file type as `JSON with comment` in VSCODE, which is a vscode-specific format known as jsonc. Have you noticed that `tsconfig.json` also supports comments?
3. I recommend using the Vscode plugin `JsonComments`. It's a handy plugin that allows you to add comments to any JSON file.
   [see preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLUeV.gif)