# npm ci can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, expo, github-actions

This is the issue that I am facing when running the command `npm ci` to install dependencies in my GitHub Action file.

I am working on an expo managed app and using `GitHub Actions` as a CI for triggering builds whenever I push my code to `developmemt` branch.

Here's my build script:

```
name: EAS PIPELINE
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Install and build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x

      - name: Setup Expo
        uses: expo/expo-github-action@v6
        with:
          expo-version: 4.x
          token: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}
          expo-cache: true

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build on EAS
        run: EAS_BUILD_AUTOCOMMIT=${{1}} npx eas-cli build --platform all --non-interactive
```

Here's the issue that I am facing `Install dependencies` step.

```
Run npm ci
  npm ci
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    EXPO_TOKEN: ***
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T15_16_06_934Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After a lot of research, I was able to figure out that this happens when you are not using `npm install` for installing dependencies. In my case, I was only using yarn for the dependencies so I was only having `yarn.lock` file and no `package-lock.json` file.

- One way to resolve this was using `npm install` to install the dependencies, then you'll have a `package-lock.json` file and `CI` won't throw any error.
- And the other way if you only want to use `yarn`, then you need to update that step in your `eas-pipeline.yml` file for installing the dependencies.

```
*****************************************************************************************

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          if [ -e yarn.lock ]; then
          yarn install --frozen-lockfile
          elif [ -e package-lock.json ]; then
          npm ci
          else
          npm i
          fi

***************************************************************************************
```

As I wasn't able to find any solution on StackOverflow and it is our first go-to place to look for any issue. So, I decided to write this answer here.

Here's the original answer: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/2846#issuecomment-691706184

Comment: Unless you want to write some generic install script that works in multiple scenarios, you probably want to stick with either `yarn` or `npm` but not mix the two. If you use `npm install` locally, use `yarn install --frozen-lockfile` in CI.

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar error:

```
`npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

with a bunch of missing dependency names following this error.

I would run `npm ci` locally and it would run successfully. However, it would give me the error above when `npm ci` is run in the CI pipeline and in my case it was because of the version difference of the Node.js installed in the environment that Jenkins pipeline is running in.

My local Node version was 16.x and in Jenkins container it was 12.x.

Upgrading it fixed.

Comment: We had the same thing happen. I'm theorizing a new version of `npm` is being a little stricter on how it checks compatibility. We're using `overrides`, and some of our developers didn't have a version of npm that respects the `overrides` in package.json.

Comment: Had the same thing too. Something between npm version 8 and 8.5 seemed to be breaking the build in the same way as you in GitHub Actions. In my case specifying `node-version: '17.9.0'` which uses npm 8.5.5 to the workflow fixed it. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: The same thing happened here, I had 16.3.2, and CI was 16 :shrug:

Comment: Downgrading my node js version to 16.0.0 worked for me

Comment: Similar story for me. I had node 16.14..0 and npm 8.3.1 in my development environment, where I ran `npm install`. The CI box had node 16.17.1 and npm 8.15.0 installed. So something has changed in npm between 8.3 and 8.15. I upgraded my development environment to be the same version as the CI environment and it built successfully.

Comment: I experienced a similar issue as well.
My local setup was using npm version ~7.18.1 while the CI pipeline uses an higher version.
Forcing the CI pipeline to use npm 7.18.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 31):

This same thing happened to me, and I couldn't figure it out for the longest time. It turns out that I had `legacy-peer-deps=true` set globally, and I had no idea.

This caused my `npm install` command to alter the `package-lock.json` in a way that broke the build on our CI server. I reset `package-lock.json` with the version from `master`, removed that `npm` config, and reinstalled. Everything worked fine after that.

Comment: For what it's worth this was the issue that was the cause for me and my team. Removing or disabling the `legacy-peer-deps` setting made my local like CI. Thanks Spencer

Comment: Thanks this was my issue. I had `legacy-peer-deps=true` in my `.npmrc` file.

Comment: I wasted hours searching for the cause of my error only to find this. You're a life saver! More like a time saver! haha. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find this before solving on my own. For what it's worth, the same is true for any other npm settings, they have to be identical.

Answer (score 26):

It looks like your package.json and package-lock.json is not synced.

Try to run this `npm install --package-lock-only`. It will generate package-lock.json that is synced on your package.json

Comment: Ensuring the package.json and package-lock.json are synced is the simplest solution here so, while it might not work for everyone, this is what I would try first. I deleted my package-lock.json and then did npm install and after that npm ci worked fine.

Answer (score 13):

Old post, but I found this while searching for this same error. In my case I *did* have a `package-lock.json` file in my root directory. However, when opening it, I realized that there was a JSON syntax error that slipped in during a previous merge conflict. After running `npm i` again the file was fixed. The `npm ERR! The 'npm ci' command can only install with an existing package-lock.json` wasn't a super helpful error in that case.

Comment: Agreed, just experienced this. It would be better if `npm` warned of a detected `package-lock.json` that is unparseable.

Answer (score 10):

I struggled for about 5 hours with AWS Amplify because apparently my package-lock.json and package.json were not synced up; nothing I did with my own code fixed the issue (even deleting the package-lock.json), what ended up working was changing my preBuild settings inside of the App build specification inside the Build Settings tab of the Amplify page.

My yml file ended up looking like this:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install --package-lock-only
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

noteably the only difference from the default is including `-npm install --package-lock-only` to sync up the files inside AWS. Maybe a bit obvious, but I got stuck on it for a few hours and hope I can help someone out down the line.

Comment: thanks that's the exact issue i was facing

Comment: Thank you mate. Same on local docker env

Comment: Confirming this worked for me also - thank you

Comment: This works perfectly within minutes. Thanks a lot. You rock @Nathaniel

Comment: Downvote because this defeats the purpose of using `npm ci` in the first place. This updates your `package-lock.json` to match your `package.json`, which is what `npm ci` is intended to avoid. You may as well just use `npm install` instead.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was running into this same issue when attempting to deploy it to Firebase. when I ran `firebase deploy --only functions` it would produce this error and fail to properly deploy the function. I attempted all of the steps here. Deleting `package-lock.json` then running `npm i` did not work. Upgrading then downgrading my node version with a node version manager (nvm) did not work.

What finely worked was deleting the package-lock.json file and **not running** `npm install` afterwards. When I ran `firebase deploy --only functions` it successfully deployed.

**BE AWARE:** Although this solution worked for me, it can lead to other complications further down the line.

Comment: Nothing else in this list worked for me but this. Thanks. A night before I deployed successfully, then a small change triggered all this issue.

Answer (score 3):

For the people who has this issue on AWS Amplify. You might have to run npm install and commit the package-lock.json file, then deploy again.

Answer (score 3):

After battling with this issue for about 2 days, It's finally deploying successfully to Firebase Functions after deleting `package-lock.json` from both the `src` and `src/functions` folders.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `pnpm`, you install node dependencies via this step:

```
      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: |
          npm i -g pnpm
          pnpm i
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurred because the package lock file was not generated with `npm`, despite the fact that the `npm ci` requires `npm` to install the packages.
And because `npm` requires `package-lock.json`, we get this error. To fix this error for GitHub actions, this what I did:

```yaml
    - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    - run: yarn lint
    - run: yarn test:ci
```

Commit diff:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had this error with `npm ci` while using Yarn. I eventually figured out the version of Node I was using wasn't supported.
I did the following:

- `node -v` to confirm my node version (18.0.1)
- `nvm use 16.13.0`
- Delete the `node_modules` directory
- Delete `yarn.lock`
- Run `yarn`
- Run `yard add` + package names

After this, the error no longer occurred and the app deployed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have regenerated your `package-lock.json` file and you're still getting the same error consider the following:

1. Ensure you are using the same node versions across environments
2. Regenerate the `package-lock.json` file with the same version you're using in your CI or docker. i.e. `npm install --package-lock-only`
3. Check your `.npmrc`, in my case, it was because `--legacy-per-deps=true` when I was trying to `npm audit --fix`

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes because of the version difference of the Node.js installed in the environment that the pipeline is running in.
To fixe this, I ran:
$ firebase init hosting:github
then type Y to set up workflow when asked to.
finally, add "npm i" as one of the scripts to run before deploying like this:
npm i && npm ci && npm run build

Answer (score 0):

I was using `npm` package manager and migrated to `yarn` package manager removing `package-lock.json` file.

I had this configuration in my `.circleci/config.yml` file

```
- node/install-packages
```

changed to

```
- node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: yarn
```

Comment: Not really a solution for "making npm work"

Comment: you are right the solution is not to make npm work but I saw a similar error message when I migrated my project from npm to yarn that is why I thought it was important adding this comment here

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem were some 'extraneous' packages, concretely local path dependencies. After removing them from package.json the problem was solved.

I got the error message while running `npm install` instead of `npm ci`.

Answer (score 0):

On *package.json* I change this :

```js
"overrides": {
    "trim-newlines": "^3.0.1"
 },
```

to : `

```js
"overrides": {
    "trim-newlines": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

`

That Work for me successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was: I have changing some dependencies in package.json, so package.json didnt matches packages.lock.json. This was the error.

Answer (score -1):

deleting deploy.json helped me, since the token is updated when overwritten

```
rm ~/.config/configstore/@vkontakte/vk-miniapps-deploy.json
```

but I have other services

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem deploying to heroku. I simply deleted the existing package-lock.json file and then ran

```
    npm install
```

Merging the new lock file fixed the deploy.