`package.yaml` instead of `package.json` in nodejs
I am missing comments in package.json and I am wondering if there is an option to use package.yaml and how obscure this idea is?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221579

As I see now, the answer is NO. Discussion on this topic you can find at Support for ./package.yml ? #3336.
