# Node Socket IO Client Windows Path too long to install

Tags: node.js, windows, sockets

I'm getting this error when trying to install browsersync. I can't get that much closer to the drive letter to make this path fit but either way it's a pretty terrible problem. This error came up in red when I ran npm install. Should I be concerned about it? Everything else seemed to have completed properly.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(308,5):
>   error MSB3491: Could n ot write lines to file
>   "Release\obj\validation\validation.tlog\validation.lastbuildstate".
>   The specified path, f ile name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the director
>   y name must be less than 248 characters.
>   [S:\prj\prjb\files\node_modules\browser-sync\node_mo
>   dules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-v
>   alidate\build\validation.vcxproj]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node npm windows file paths are too long to install packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155135/node-npm-windows-file-paths-are-too-long-to-install-packages)

Answer (score 1):

1. go to `S:\prj\prjb\files\node_modules\browser-sync\` that folder
2. Inside that folder, run `npm install -f`

   That makes the path shorter to install socket.io bundled in browser-sync.