# Npm package install failure

Tags: node.js, nuget-package, package-managers

Trying to learn nodejs following a few articles.  I'm able to download and make sure its working using a video from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_).  But now I'm trying to incorporate that in Visual Studio .net 4.5.2.  I've tried to added it via new get package manager and the PM console each come back to same error.

"Install-Package: The specified path, file or both are to long. Less than 260 and directory name less than 248"  Self explanatory, found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155135/node-npm-windows-file-paths-are-too-long-to-install-packages)

So I tried:
npm-flatten
npm-dedupe
also Enable Win32 long paths

It starts adding package npm 3.5.2 files and folders then bombs out and spits the same error.  What else am I missing in order to get this package installed?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you mention the command specifically you are trying on nuget package manager ? What is the version that you want. Its always recommended to install the LTM version

Comment: I've used Install-Package Npm | Install-Package npm.js | and nuget install npm.js all have failed  with this error: Install-Package : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 
characters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package npm.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand