# create-react-app RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededat Object.mkdirSync

Tags: reactjs, cmd, create-react-app, npm-install, windows-defender

Today I tried to create new react app using (`create-react-app app-name`) in CMD and this error appeared :

```
PS C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\My File\New Folder\New Folder JS\New Folder> create-react-app testing-app
C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:49
          throw err0
          ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:738:10) ...
```

Also, the installation will be stuck if I try to install any package in this folder like `prop-type`, I tried to update my `node` as well `create-react-app` but nothing change. I solved this problem by creating my react app in `C:\Users\ahmed` not in `C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\My File\New Folder\New Folder JS\New Folder`
So my question is: why I can't create react app in a long path like `C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\My File\New Folder\New Folder JS\New Folder` why it needs to be created in `C:\Users \username`?

Comment: [This might be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37528731/11020515)

Comment: refer this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936486/node-js-maximum-call-stack-size- exceeded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the solution to my problem.
my problem was I tried to creating new react app using `npm create-react-app app-name` in `CMD`.
If I try to create react in `C:\Users\user-name\` it will install all the packages and react app will work. But in my case, I tried to create react in different location `C:\Users\user-name\folder\folder\folder`and shows the above error.
I find many solutions most of them tried to edit `npmrc` file in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`, add or delete same `confg` in this file. but nothing works !!!
when I create react app the error shows in `CMD` but at the same time **windows defender show this message**

> **unathorised changes blocked
>
>   controlled folder access blocked C:\program\File...\node.exe from making changes to the folder C:\Users\user-name\folder\folder\folder**

So, the solution was is to stop windows defender and `create-react-app` works in any location. you can stop windows defender by using different methods [stop Windows defender](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10). in my case, I stop Real-time protection, you can do that in windows 10:
`settings > update & Security > windows security > virus & threat protection > virus & threat protection settings > Real-time protection "off"`.
But the best solution is to add `node app` as trust app in Windows defender settings or disable controlled folder access, you can do that by following this link [Use controlled folder access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046851/windows-10-allow-blocked-app-windows-security)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to clear npm cache. Using following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 1):

The above problem can be solved using the following approach:

- If you're on windows, turn off windows defender and then retry create-react-app command. Mostly this should work. If the above solution doesn't work go for the next step.

  - Clear NPM cache by using the following command:

  npm cache clean --force

Now, again retry create-react-app command. This worked like magic for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem
It comes from windows defender and firewall .
So add node.exe to the exceptions for windows defender and firewall and it may work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu. I just used sudo create-react-app my-app and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

### Option Resolution

Another reason you might be experiencing this issue specifically on **Windows** is due to *spaces* in your file path.

Make sure that your file path does not spaces, only "_" or camelCase.

Good Example

```
C:\Users\user.name\projects\project_01
```

Bad Example

```
C:\Users\user.name\projects\project 01
```