# Unable to publish VS project to Azure due to file name length despite having shortened temporary directory

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2013, publish

I am unable to publish a project to Azure from Visual Studio. I am running into an issue because I am getting the following error:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I have already tried many common solutions. The problem arises in the temporary directory location, but I have shortened this. The directory that is too long is `b:\test\WebSitePublish\WebProject-1309592107\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\node_modules\grunt-bower\node_modules\bower\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration\test-delayed-http-upload.js`, starting with a short directroy name.

I have also tried installing `npm install -g flatten-packages` but get the same error.

How can I make this project push?

Comment: Can you [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) the project to a root directory then publish? robocopy /e /r:1 /w:0 b:\test\WebSitePublish\WebProject-1309592107 b:\pub\WP-1309592107

Comment: I'm already operating very close to the drive root (at b:\test), I don't think getting rid of four more characters will solve it, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: regarding your edit, b:\test is what comes up when I already try to deploy. It contains the temporary files. I'm not sure how to grab and copy at the intermediate level like that. I am pressing publish, and then these files are being copied to b:\test and giving an error in `__VSDeploymentFailure__.txt.`

Comment: 24 characters , WebSitePublish\WebProject - excluding WP. what is the root directory for the project?

Comment: root directroy is b:\dw . How do I copy the temporary files generated from when I select publish?

Comment: so you're publishing your project with a related test project that has some lengthy file names?

Comment: Ugh, isn't this just the most frustrating thing? :( I've run into this so much while developing with node on windows. `</rant>` However, if you're trying to publish, you shouldn't actually need node's build tools, just the output. I am unfamiliar with azure so I don't know if it is trying to be too smart about things, but is there any way you can build the files pre-publish?

Comment: Also, check this solution out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18472948/998328

Comment: @lloydm the test name is probably not the best. I have set the temporary output directory for the project to be in b:\test instead of %appdata%\whatever.

Comment: @CarrieKendall yes, incredibly frustrating. Azure is just what I am publishing to, and publishing from VS seems to be the easiest way to do this. The problem is that I'm also getting long file names in the intermedium. I'll try the solution you linked to though, thanks!